# Unable to Access Shared Folders in Our Own Machine using NTLM: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: java, ntlm, smb, jcifs, fileshare

I am working on NTLM Implementation with Java. I am trying to access shared folders inside my own machine. But I get the following Exception:

```
 jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

I got the machine name and workgroup info from computer properties. Here is my Code:

```
String folderUrl =settings.domain+";"+settings.username+":"+settings.password
NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("${folderUrl}") ;
 SmbFile readFolder = new SmbFile("smb:"+settings.filesLocation+"/",authentication) ;
```

And in this line I get the above exception:

```
SmbFile[] listOfFiles = readFolder.listFiles() ;
```

**Solution Tried So far:**

I made change in Local Security Policy and change the value of "Network Security: LAN Manager Authentication Level" to "Send NLM & NTLM, use session security if negotiated" but all in vain. Furthermore, I tried by changing password and domain as well.

**Note:**

1. I have created shared folders and these are visible in 'Network' as shared
2. I am unable to access my machine through other machines on the same network, don't know why, May be this is the reason. Have a look at error that what I get when I try to access my machine from some other machine on the same network with same credential I use to enter in my pc:

[image]

Please guide me how can I make my application to access these shared folders on network path using NTLM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, Issue was with the Windows LogIn user (Don't know what was that issue actually) I was using to access shared folder. So, I just created another new windows user and tried to access those shared folders with newly created window user and shared folders were accessible successfully without any issue.

Alongwith this new user my machine was accessible from others machine on the same network.

Comment: Did you ever found the reason why the old Windows user didn't permit the access? I have the same problem.

Comment: No didn't get much time to dig into it further. Did the above-mentioned solution do the trick?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the system administrator of that host, so I can't create a new user.